# Retaining Line Feeds used in xml while transforming the xml using xsl

Tags: xslt

I am transforming an xml using an xsl.I get the xml from Oracle database.When i transform I am unable to see the data in the format it was actually stored.In a particular node, the line feeds used which are seen in the xml but when i transform I am unable t see the line feeds.All the content in the particluar node is displayed in a line.

Can some one help me in how to include the line feeds which are already there in the xml???

Thanks
Raghav

Comment: There are two possibilities here: The XSLT processor's not preserving the white space (likely if you're using MSXML), or it is, but whatever you're using to display it isn't showing the line feeds. If your output is shown as part of an html document, this would happen.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a test that helps determine the cause of the observed problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, if you're using MSXML then check that it's configured to preserve whitespace.

Also check that the stylesheet doesn't use `<xsl:strip-space>`.

Also, if you are using XSLT 2.0 then whitespace is stripped by default for elements defined in a DTD or schema as having element-only content.

Also, it's possible of course that your stylesheet code is doing something with the whitespace text nodes other than copying them to the output.

Answer (score 0):

XML and derivitives compress white space so to the parser, they don't matter.
Some parsers however have the option to preserve white space.
In MSXML, you set the DomDocument's preserveWhiteSpace property to true.

Comment: Not true, XML preserves whitespace by default (at least it's supposed to. MSXML doesn't).

Comment: @Flynn1179 is right, besides new line and attribute value normalization: from http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends : *XML processor MUST behave as if it normalized all line breaks in external parsed entities (including the document entity) on input, before parsing, by translating both the two-character sequence #xD #xA and any #xD that is not followed by #xA to a single #xA character* and from http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize : *For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value*

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In case the linebreaks are still not displayed, this means that the XML parser is stripping-off all whitespace-only text nodes. Read the documentation how to invoke the parser so that this default action is suppressed -- like as suggested in Deanna's answer for MSXML.

**In case the result from the above transformation does contain the linebreaks, then you are doing something in the code** you haven't shown to us, that causes these linebreaks not to be displayed.